# Reading date from user input and passing to two functions

Tags: sql, python-3.x, tkinter, tkinter-entry

I am using tkinter, I read date inputs inserted by user from front end and I pass these dates as arguments to 2 functions.

- 1st function uses the format `02-APR-2018 01.01.00 AM`
- 2nd function uses the format `2018-04-02 00:00:00`.

I am not sure how to pass the same date that is read by the user into these two functions. And these two dates are actually read as a part of SQL query in my python program. I've been stuck for days. Appreciate quick help.

I also get this error when I try passing date as of now:

```
cursor1.execute(myquery1)
```

> cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Answer (score 1):

Make a rule for the user input for one format and you can always convert that to the other format I guess.

Comment: i tried the same for 1 function, it throws cx_Oracle.DatabaseError: ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected, do you think i need to define the input variable as a date variable? if yes, then how?